# How to fix empty tensorflow installation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow, gpu

I get illegal instruction (core dumped) after running import tensorflow with version of tensorflow 1.7.

After that I installed tf 1.5.0-gpu (pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.5.0)

Then tried to import tensorflow, I get no error
However `tf.set_random_seed(random_state)` - returns `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'set_random_seed'`

Then in the jupyter notebook with `shit-tab` get library help:

```
Type:        module
String form: <module 'tensorflow' (namespace)>
Docstring:   <no docstring>
```

Seems to isnt righ. However :

```
 ~ $ pip show tensorflow-gpu
Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 1.5.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/analyst/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: absl-py, wheel, six, tensorflow-tensorboard, numpy, protobuf
Required-by: 

$ pip show tensorflow  #Returns nothing
```

What might be wrong?

UPD: I have such files, which can be  found via search. Im afraid of 1.1.0 tf. Is it okay?

```
>qqusr@qqusr-PC ~ $ locate -i tensorflow.py
/home/qqusr/anaconda3/pkgs/tensorflow-1.1.0-np112py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py
/home/qqusr/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/dist_test/scripts/k8s_tensorflow.py
```

upd: I have 2 active namaspaces: how to fix that:

```
> tf.__path__

_NamespacePath(['/home/aa/tensorflow', '/home/aa/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow'])
```

Comment: do you have a file called tensorflow.py in your environment?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Updated the question

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19729 github issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) One method that worked for @JaeDukSeo was using the precomplied version
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow

In addition you give this a try and for precomplied GPU version: https://github.com/mind/wheels.

2) However, installing precomputed version leads me to another error, problems with intel libraries. Trying to solve such problem I found the solution
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu

You can specify here version you want to install as well